# ifelse() anidado con varias condiciones

Tags: r, tidyverse

Estoy intentando hacer una comparación con `ifelse()` para obtener unos datos, pero no consigo obtener la combinación adecuada, siempre me devuelve algún error. Intento poner un ejemplo genérico para explicarme. Mi idea es la siguiente:

```
ifelse(conducion1 & (condicion2 o condicion3), resultado1, ifelse(condicion4 & condicion5, resultado2, resultado3))
```

La condicion 2 y 3 es sobre una misma variable (columna).

Pues eso, no hay forma de que me salga.

Gracias.

Editado.

Pues sería un ejemplo así:

```
df1
id    p1    p2
id1   inc   inc
id2   esc   inc
id3   esc   esc
id4   inc   esc

df2
id    p1    p2
id1   inc   neg
id2   8     inc
id3   10    neg
id4   inc   5
```

Quiero generar un 3er df en el que se cumplan las condiciones siguientes para cada una de las variables:

```
df3 <- ifelse(df1[2:3] == "inc" & (df2[2:3] == "inc" | df2[2:3] == "neg"), "correcto", ifelse(df2[2:3] != "inc" & df1[2:3] == "esc", "correcto", "comprobar"))
```

Ya aviso que no tengo claro que el código esté bien.

Gracias.

---

A ver si consigo explicarlo bien.

Tengo un df (df_res) con diferentes variables que pueden tomar valores numéricos, "inc" o "neg" (es el df2 de mi pregunta). En este caso, todas las filas son únicas. Este df sale de otro (df_ori) en que tengo entradas repetidas (3 "caso1", 2 "caso 2"... por ejemplo). Los valores del df_res, como digo, provienen del df_ori; es una toma de decisión en relación al conjunto de valores que aparecen en el df_ori.

El problema está en que hemos detectado unos errores en esa toma de decisiones, y tememos que haya más. Por tanto, se me había ocurrido la siguiente idea para intentar detectarlos:

1. Genero un df (df3) que me diga cuántos "inc" hay en el df_ori para cada caso.
2. Genero otro df (df4) que me diga cuántas repeticiones hay de cada caso del df_ori.
3. Comparo df3 con df4, para generar el df1 de la pregunta. Si df3 y df4 coinciden en el valor, aparece un "inc", si no, un "esc". En este caso, el "inc" y el "esc" no tienen importancia, son simplemente indicatorios, podría haber optado por cualquier otra nomenclatura.
4. Entonces llegamos a la comparación que quiero hacer en el `ifelse()` para detectar los errores.
5. si en df_res hay un "inc" o "neg" y en df1 hay "inc", le atribuyo el resultado "correcto", si en df_res hay algo diferente a "inc" y en df1 hay "esc", también le asigno el valor "correcto"; en el resto de casos, le asigno el valor "comprobar". Así obtengo un df que me dice qué combinaciones de casos/variables tengo que volver a comprobar.

Pero me estoy liando con el `ifelse()`

Disculpad el trabalenguas de df. No sé si he conseguido dejarlo claro.

Gracias.

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo más concreto para facilitar la ayuda? En cualquier caso, trataría de hacerlo con if + else, en lugar de la función `ifelse()` que en algunos casos puede resultar problemática.

Comment: Hecho! Gracias.

Comment: Ok, ahora se ve mejor. Sólo nos falta saber cuál es el output que esperas y cuáles son las condiciones (de palabra) que determinan los valores.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que buscas hacer con está condición `df1[2:3] == "inc"`? ¿Podrías explicar las condiciones que deseas implementar?

Comment: Lo explico en una respuesta, que me paso de caracteres por aquí. Gracias a ambos.